# SQL Recursion separation path between students

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQLand I'm having trouble constructing a recursive SQL query. 
I need to find all the names of the students who are up to 3 degrees of separation away from a specific student named John Smith.

I have a table of students (sid, name) and a table of student-course relationships StudentInCourse(sid, courseNumber) where each student can be enrolled in multiple courses and each course can have multiple students enrolled in it. How can I write a recursive SQL query to accomplish this?

Assume that two students are 1 degree of separation away if they are both enrolled in the same course, two students are 2 degrees of separation away if there exists another student who is enrolled in the same course as both of them, and three students are 3 degrees of separation away if there exists a student who is 1 degree of separation away from 2 students who are themselves 2 degrees of separation away from each other.

**EDIT:** 
I need to add a condition that the separation degree is only calculated between students with the same major. That means the degree is 2 if both students have the same major and one of them was in another course with John Smith who also had the same major.
One student can be in a few majors.
HERE is the code tried using the help of @Mike Organek:

[link to code](https://dbfiddle.uk/aaNb0bA1)

Comment: Please post some entries into the tables you mentioned and the desired output of the query you want ,based on the entries in the tables.

Comment: Focus your recursion on getting the distances between `courseNumber` values, and then add in the joins to the students:  https://dbfiddle.uk/X3a3TsTg

Comment: @MikeOrganek thank you very much! we tried to add major condition in which the separation degree is only calculated upon student with the same major. Meaning that it is 2 if both students have the same major, and one of them was on another course with John Smith with the same major. I tried to write this code using the one you provided but it didn't work - https://dbfiddle.uk/aaNb0bA1

Answer (score 1):

The following query demonstrates using a recursive query to determine degrees of separation:

```
WITH RECURSIVE students(sid, name) AS (
    VALUES (1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C'), (4, 'D'), (5, 'E'), (6, 'F'), (7, 'G')
),
students_courses(sid, cid) AS (
    VALUES (1, 1),(1, 2),(2, 1),(2, 3),(3, 3),(3, 4),(4, 4),(5, 4),(4, 5),(6, 5)
),
anchor(sid) AS (VALUES (1)),
cte AS (
    SELECT 
        1 AS student_distance,
        ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT s.sid) FILTER (WHERE s.sid <> anchor.sid) AS students,
        ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT sc.cid) AS visited_courses,
        ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT s.sid) AS visited_students
    FROM anchor
    JOIN students_courses sc ON anchor.sid = sc.sid
    JOIN students_courses s ON sc.cid = s.cid
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        cte.student_distance + 1 AS student_distance,
        n.students,
        cte.visited_courses || n.visited_courses AS visited_courses,
        cte.visited_students || n.visited_students AS visited_students
    FROM cte
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT
            ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT s.sid) AS students,
            ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT sc.cid) AS visited_courses,
            ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT s.sid) AS visited_students
        FROM students_courses sc
        JOIN students_courses s
            ON sc.cid = s.cid AND s.sid <> ALL (cte.visited_students)
        WHERE sc.sid = ANY (cte.students)
            AND sc.cid <> ALL (cte.visited_courses)) n
    WHERE n.students IS NOT NULL
        AND n.students <> '{}'
)
SELECT
    cte.student_distance,
    s.sid,
    s.name,
    cte.students,
    cte.visited_courses,
    cte.visited_students
FROM cte
JOIN students s ON s.sid = ANY (cte.students)
WHERE cte.student_distance <= 3
ORDER BY cte.student_distance, s.sid;
```

The first two CTE's, `students` and `students_courses` are demonstration data. The third CTE, `anchor`, is used to avoid repeating a literal value later in the query.

The initialization stage sets the initial distance and collects the anchor student's courses and fellow classmates in those courses into `visited_courses` and `students`, respectively. The anchor student and fellow students are also collected into `visited_students`.

The recursive portion increments the distance and identifies previously unvisited courses associated with students found in the previous iteration. Previously unvisited students in those courses are collected into `students`. The newly visited courses and students are merged into `visited_courses` and `visited_students`, respectively. This process repeats until no unvisited students are found (this could also have a termination condition base on distance).

The results from this query are shown below:

| student_distance | sid | name | students | visited_courses | visited_students |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | B | `{2}` | `{1,2}` | `{1,2}` |
| 2 | 3 | C | `{3}` | `{1,2,3}` | `{1,2,3}` |
| 3 | 4 | D | `{4,5}` | `{1,2,3,4}` | `{1,2,3,4,5}` |
| 3 | 5 | E | `{4,5}` | `{1,2,3,4}` | `{1,2,3,4,5}` |

The columns `students`, `visited_courses`, and `visited_students` have been included to show the tracking details that were collected at each iteration.